# Insert pdf into appendix

Tags: errors, pdfpages

I am unsuccessful inserting a pdf into an appendix of my thesis. I get the error `Latex Error: can be used only in preamble`. Also, it says unable to locate file `Python_program.pdf` where I have stored my other `.jpg`, `.png` pics. StackExchange has varying solutions to this problem, none of which work for me.

The code I am using is:

```
\chapter[Appendix D]{Python Code}
\label{chp:appendix_D}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{Python_program.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Erh why are you placing a chanpter command in the preamble? It belongs in the document body. So given the error you cite I don't quite believe this example is actually the document you are trying to use. Please update your question with a complete example

Comment: This is the code I am using. If you can suggest an edit that would be great. I tried putting \usepackage{pdfpages} at the top of the page, but it still failed. Thanks.

Comment: That code can never work as there is no documentclass and chapter needs to go into the document part. I'd suggest you go read a proper introduction to latex instead of dealing with a mess like this